# The effect of println statements in production?

Tags: performance, grails

I was reviewing the Grails application code and i found println statements in a lot of places. These were used for debugging. I am wondering whether leaving these statements affect the production app performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it affects in production environment, because println statements are **synchronous**. Without processing your println statements execution will not move forward, if you are printing huge size objects like Map, List, file content etc, this will take more execution time and increase the log file size as well, so this will definitely affect your production performance.

The better way is if you want to maintain the logs use **Log4J** like **asynchronous** library for auditing  your important logs in the application.
[Log4j reference](http://grails-dev.blogspot.in/2012/09/setting-up-log4j-configuration-in.html)

Comment: thanks ill remove all the printlns and use a debugger instead. thanks!